# Is this considered a selection sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I was practicing a while ago and came across **selection sort**. After some research across difference sources, there are some that declare an array then delete the current min location while others swap within the array

I tried to use ES6 for some trivial functions, did not use map since I wanted to understand the loop on a whiteboard.

Is this considered a selection sort?

```js
selectionSortNoSwap = list)= => {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list; i++) {
    const min = Math.min(...list);
    const minIndex = list.indexOf(min);

    result.push(min);
    list.splice(minIndex, 1);
  }

  return result;
};

selectionSortNoSwap([3, 5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No. True selection sort sorts *in-place*, rather than creating another array. That is, given:

```
[3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

after the first iteration, a selection sort should produce the following data structure in memory:

```
[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
```

where the 1 and 3 have been exchanged - and not

```
[3, 5, 2, 4]
[1]
```

If elements are not swapped with each other, it's not selection sort.

To sort in-place, you'd need something like

```js
const selectionSort = (list) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // for convenience - or use a for loop 
    const min = Math.min(...list.slice(i));
    const minIndex = list.indexOf(min, i);
    [list[i], list[minIndex]] = [list[minIndex], list[i]];
  }
  return list;
};

console.log(selectionSort([3, 5, 2, 1, 4]));
```